# timer event getting executed on form object creation

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, messagebox

I am using c#.net win forms.I have 2 forms namely 'Form1' & 'Form2'.Now in Form1 there is a button which when clicked,shows the Form2 as follows:

```
private void btnBegin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmTestRail fT = new frmTestRail();
        this.Hide();
        fT.ShowDialog();
    }
```

In Form2, among various controls there is one timer control which has been programmed to tick every 60 seconds for the next 40 minutes.The timer starts for the first time in the Form_Load event of Form2.Actually in the tick event of the timer it has codes which executes certain update queries in the table.After 40 minutes a message box is shown to the user that the timer has been stopped now.
Constructor of Form2 looks like this:

```
    public frmTestRail()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConFirebirdSQL"].ConnectionString;
    }
```

Now my problem is that When i click the show button in Form1, the above mentioned message box of Form2 momentarily shows up which is not desired at that stage.I guess this is happening because when i am creating an instance of Form2, all the components or controls of Form2 are getting initialized along with the timer control and its tick events.How do i stop the message box from popping up when show button is clicked from Form1. I hope i make myself clear.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the Timer enabled by default? If so, you can disable it until you want it enabled. You can disable it in code, if need be, using this sort of thing (this is, of course, for a different control and a different event, but you get the picture):
comboBoxPUBeginMonth.SelectedIndexChanged -= comboBoxMonth_SelectedIndexChanged;

Comment: Yes the Timer is enabled by default.Yes i can enable it in code but i am enabling it by default, because the Form2 is a Quiz form showing various questions to user.hence as soon as the Form2 is shown to the user the quiz starts and so the count down timer

Comment: @Shannon thanks for your reply.Your reply has prompted me to incorporate some design changes in form2. Now i have added a button which when clicked would start the timer.